# Python - decoding a PNG image for JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.7, Flask 1.1.1, SQLAlchemy 1.3.9

I have a Flask server, which connects with a MySQL database and returns records. One table contains (among other info) a uuid and a PNG image. I want to send this model over HTTP, but am running into issues with JSON. Let's call the record `record`.

> resp = record.__dict__

I can't send resp directly, as Python raises `TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable`. I haven't found a way to decode the image to a String (utf-8 won't work). I tried

> json.dumps(resp, sort_keys=True, default=str)

But I can't parse the resulting string back to the original image this way.

How can I decode the image in a way that allows it to be sent by JSON, and restored to the image later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about use base64?
If the resp is the images's bytes data.

```py
import base64
resp_b64_string = base64.b64encode(resp).decode("u8")
```

Comment: Hi @DustyPosa, thanks for the response. This is precisely what I was looking for.
I can get the original image back using base64.b64decode(resp_b64_string.encode()).
Thank you so much!